# SUBIR ARCHIVO ZIP DE UN PROYECTO A OTRO PROYECTO CON PHP

Tags: php

Por favor su apoyo.

Cómo puedo hacer para poder subir un archivo zip y luego se descomprime y se guarde en una carpeta de mi proyecto 1, el formulario para cargar los archivos será desde mi proyecto 2, y debe de guardarse en la carpeta documento/documento de mi proyecto 1
Tengo este código de carga:

```
//<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == 
"POST") {
// Obtener la carpeta seleccionada 
y establecer la ruta de carga
$uploadPath =  "D:/xampp/htdocs/Documentos/formatos_pdf/";

// Comprobar si la carpeta existe
if (!is_dir($uploadPath)) {
    echo "La carpeta de carga no existe.";
    exit;
}

// Subir archivo zip
$zipFile = $_FILES["zipFile"]["tmp_name"];
$zipFileName = $_FILES["zipFile"]["name"];
$zipExtension = pathinfo($zipFileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

// Compruebe si el archivo tiene una extensión válida
if (strtolower($zipExtension) === "zip") {
    $destination = $uploadPath . $zipFileName;

    // Mover el archivo cargado al destino
    if (!move_uploaded_file($zipFile, $destination)) {
        echo "No se pudo cargar el archivo: $zipFileName";
        exit;
    }

    // Extrae el contenido del archivo zip.
    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    if ($zip->open($destination) === TRUE) {
        $zip->extractTo($uploadPath);
        $zip->close();
        echo '<script>alert("Archivo zip cargado y extraído correctamente."); window.location.href = "../home/CargarArchivos.php";
        </script>';
        //Eliminar el archivo zip cargado
        unlink($destination);
        
        
        


    } else {
        echo "No se pudo extraer el archivo zip.";
    }
} else {
    echo "Extensión de archivo inválida: $zipExtension. Sólo se permiten archivos zip.";
}
} else {

echo "Método de solicitud no válido.";
}


?>
```

Actualmentente apunta entre ruta de mi misma máquina, pero quiero que apunte a la carpeta que ya está alojado en el servidor.
Ambos proyectos están en el mismo servidor